# Does Google My Business free website influence the SEO of main website?

Tags: seo, google-business

If a business has already built a dedicated website, does setup the Google My Business free website (name.business.site) influence the ranking of the main website (positively or negatively)?

Comment: Short Answer: Directly No, but indirectly Yes.

Comment: why do you want to create duplicated content?

Answer (score 1):

A Google My Business website is not meant to supplement your main website; it is meant to be a means of getting small business owners who cannot afford to pay a web developer and don't want to bother with complicated and potentially expensive CMS setups to get a basic site, with limited functionality, up on the web.

The reasons why Google is offering this vary. One is to encourage people to get on to Google My Business, since those little websites are integrated with GMB. The other is to make it easy for people to enter precise data about their business, because GMB can be hard to navigate. Finally, Google just likes data collection and also wants you to use their products.

However, other than a few links to your website, the GMB website will only make things confusing for users. Do you really want people going to that one, instead of your main website? Is a GMB website how you want to make a first impression with the user, rather than your own site? How will the info on GMB website differ from your main site info, as @Yevgeniy alluded to above?

The optimal solution is to keep your main website as your true website, and to get yourself on GMB as a listing and an entity. GMB websites are best left to folks who don't already have one, and don't want to invest any money or too much time.